# Crear trigger que no permita editar un registro que haya sido referenciado

Tags: sql-server, trigger

nececito ayuda con una consigna de un trabajo que me han dado en la universidad para estudiar, y he estado trantando de resolverlo pero no se me ocurre como.. me estoy iniciando en SQL Server.

Estas son las tablas del enunciado
[image: Tablas]:

El enunciado dice:
- Crear trigger que no permita editar un subrubro que ya haya sido referenciado por una publicación.

Si me pudieran dar la solucion seria de agradecer

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. En su estado actual, la pregunta suena como si quisieras que alguien resuelva la tarea que te han dado. Eso difícilmente va a ocurrir en StackOverflow. La idea del sitio, en el caso de tareas escolares, es que demuestres que te has esforzado y entonces seguro alguien te echa un cable para que logres terminarla. Eso usualmente se logra publicando el código de lo que has intentado, explicando tu idea y en qué no te e está funcionando. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la informacion, es la primera vez que posteaba algo, lo tendre en cuenta para la proxima vez que quiera postear algo muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías hacer algo como esto:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MiTrigger]
  ON [dbo].[Subrubro]
  FOR UPDATE
  AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.PublicacioneXRubro AS PXR JOIN inserted i ON PXR.IdSubrubro=i.Id)
      BEGIN
        RAISERROR('No puede editar un subrubro que tenga una publicación asociada', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        SET NOCOUNT OFF
        RETURN
      END
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    END
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: Funciona perfecto y ya entendi la logica.. muchas gracias!